# Bitmap Button with attached text label in wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

How do I create a bitmap button with attached text label in wxpyython. I have not come across any such generic buttons till now. I believe I will have to create one myself. How do I do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "with attached text label"  What does this mean?

Comment: It seems so! My bad, I didn't know what to search for. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

Look at the wx.lib.buttons module for various flavors of generic buttons.

Also, in the 2.9 release series the stock button class (wx.Button) can have a bitmap + text label.